# AngularJS Directive to add class on click, but remove and add it to another element if clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a simple directive that I use to add a class on click and remove it from the element if clicked again.  However I'd like to refactor it for a more common use in generic menus.  Instead if a `<li>` element is clicked that is not the current active element, it should remove it from the current element and place it on the new one.  Basically I want to add an "active" class to the `<li>` element that is currently active.

In my menu I have:

```
<ul>
    <li><a swapit ng-click="lol(stillgot)" class="select-show">Still Got Game</a></li>
    <li><a swapit ng-click="lol(thick)" class="select-show">TnT</a></li>
    <li><a swapit ng-click="lol(seldon)" class="select-show">Seldon</a></li>
    <li><a swapit ng-click="lol(hit)" class="select-show">HitMan</a></li>
    <li><a swapit ng-click="lol(community)" class="select-show">Community</a></li>
</ul>

.directive('swapit', function() {

  return {
    restrict : 'A',

    link : function(scope, elem) {

      var currentState = true;

      elem.on('click', function() {
        console.log('You clicked me!');

        if(currentState === true) {
          console.log('It is on!');
          angular.element(elem).addClass('active');
        } else {
          console.log('It is off!');
          angular.element(elem).removeClass('active');
        }

        currentState = !currentState;

      });


    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can avoid DOM manipulation and allow for reuse if you utilize isolate scope and `ng-class`:

**Directive:**

```
.directive('swapit', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      active: '='
    },
    template: '<a ng-click="active = $id" ng-class="{active: $id === active}" ng-transclude></a>'
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<swapit active="active">Still got game</swapit>
<swapit active="active">TnT</swapit>
...
```

By using isolate scope, each directive element will have its own scope with a unique ID, which can be accessed through `scope.$id`. When a directive element is clicked on, you can assign this value to an `active` scope variable, which is shared between your directives.

```
ng-click="active = $id"
```

Then, you can use `ng-class` with an expression which determines whether each directive element's scope ID matches that of the currently active scope ID:

```
ng-class="{active: $id === active}"
```

View this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dch2R2svHrl9zgJiDl2F?p=preview), which more closely matches your implementation (though not 100%).

Comment: How would this affect my current senerio though where I've already got an ng-click bound to a function that loads in other content?

Comment: Take a look at the demo: you can still have `ng-click` handle other tasks

Comment: In the demo, I still call the `lol` function on click by using the [`&` isolate scope setting](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/oEo8ZAXv27/angularjs-isolate-scope) on an attribute, which allows you to make internal calls to parent functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a directive that does that:

---

<sub>BTW, you can specify a name for the togglable group, so you can have multiple "menus" on the same page (without one interfering with the other). E.g.:</sub>

```
<li ... toggle="site-menu">Page 1</li>
<li ... toggle="site-menu">Page 2</li>
...
<li ... toggle="whatever-submenu">Option 1</li>
<li ... toggle="whatever-submenu">Option 2</li>
```

---

```
app.directive('toggle', function () {
  var TOGGLE_CLASS = 'selected';
  var groups = {};

  function addElement(groupName, elem) {
    var list = groups[groupName] || (groups[groupName] = []);
    if (list.indexOf(elem) === -1) {
      list.push(elem);
    }
  }

  function removeElement(groupName, elem) {
    var list = groups[groupName] || [];
    var idx = list.indexOf(elem);
    if (idx !== -1) {
      list.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  }

  function setActive(groupName, elem) {
    angular.forEach(groups[groupName], function (el) {
      el.removeClass(TOGGLE_CLASS);
    });
    elem.addClass(TOGGLE_CLASS);
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var groupName = attrs.toggle || 'default';
      addElement(groupName, elem);

      elem.on('click', function () {
        setActive(groupName, elem);
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        removeElement(groupName, elem);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
<a href="" toggle="test" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5]">Link {{$index + 1}}</a>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/8qWPS/)**.